# Cassandra - Data Modeling Time Series - Avoiding "Hot Spots"?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, datastax, nosql

I'm working on a Cassandra data model to store records uploaded by users.

The potential problem is, some users may upload 50-100k rows in a 5 minute period, which can result in a "hot spot" for the partiton key (user_id). (Datastax recommendation is to rethink data model if more than 10k rows per partition).

How can I avoid having too many records on a partition key in a short amount of time?

I've tried using the [Time Series suggestions from Datastax](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling), but even if I had year, month, day, hour columns, a hot spot may still occur.

```
CREATE TABLE uploads (
    user_id text
   ,rec_id timeuuid
   ,rec_key text
   ,rec_value text
   ,PRIMARY KEY (user_id, rec_id)
);
```

The use cases are:

- Get all upload records by user_id
- Search for upload records by date range
  range

Comment: Can you post an example query that you might try?  That will help in determining a useful time bucket.

Comment: 1) select rec_id, rec_key, rec_value from uploads where user_id = 'fred';

Comment: 2) select rec_id, rec_key, rec_value from uploads where user_id = 'fred' and rec_id >= maxTimeuuid('2015-01-01 00:00+0000')
   AND rec_id < minTimeuuid('2015-02-01 00:00+0000')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few possible ideas:

1. Use a compound partition key instead of just user_id.  The second part of the partition key could be a random number from 1 to n.  For example if n were 5, then your uploads would be spread out over five partitions per user instead of just one.  The downside is when you do reads, you have to repeat them n times to read all the partitions.
2. Have a separate table to handle incoming uploads using the rec_id as the partition key.  This would spread the load of uploads equally across all the available nodes.  Then to get that data into the table with user_id as the partition key, periodically run a spark job to extract new uploads and add them to the user_id based table at a rate the the single partitions can handle.
3. Modify your front end to throttle the rate at which an individual user can upload records.  If only a few users are uploading at a high enough rate to cause a problem, it may be easier to limit them rather than modify your whole architecture.

Comment: In approach 1, doesn't the degree of spreading out depend on the degree of randomness of the generated number? It would be hard to guarantee the prevention of hotspots. The only deterministic way would be to use a true / hardware random number generator where randomness is guaranteed.