outer join in pyspark between a huge DF and a very small DF
I'm trying to make an outer join of DF A (with 433 Million rows) and DF B (with 14 rows) in PySpark and I have directly a OOM error. Does Spark is not good for this kind of join ?
result = DF1.join(broadcast(DF2), how='outer', on='key_column')

I have looked at the broadcast join and the partitioning by join key but is not working in my case. Do you have any other solution ?
Here is my conf:
use-spark --driver-memory 16G --executor-memory 40G --executor-cores 6

I've activated autoBroadcast:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "256MB")

But when I do explain, I see it is not using the braodcast:
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [coalesce(CD_TYP#11, CD_TYP#40) AS CD_TYP#3095, col1#8L, col2#9L, col3#10, col4#12, col5#13, col6#14, col7#15, col8#16, col9#17L, col10#18, col11#19, col12#20, col13#21, col14#22, col15#23, col16#41]
   +- SortMergeJoin [CD_TYP#11], [CD_TYP#40], FullOuter
      :- Sort [CD_TYP#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(CD_TYP#11, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=6329]
      :     +- FileScan parquet [all calls-names replaced for security-] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[abfs://data-an@datalakeprod.dfs.core.windows.net/data/v1.0.0/20240..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<col1:bigint,col2:bigint,col3:string,col4:string,col5:timestamp,NO...
      +- Sort [CD_TYP#40 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(CD_TYP#40, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=6330]
            +- FileScan parquet [CD_TYP#40,LB_TYP#41] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[abfs://data-an@datalakeprod.dfs.core.windows.net/data/v1.0.0/20240..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<CD_TYP:string,LB_TYP:string>


24/05/16 14:48:31 WARN HintErrorLogger: Hint (strategy=broadcast) is not supported in the query: build right for full outer join.

Then I make a count or I try to write the table to really execute the join and the error is:
Executor lost connection due to JVM Out Of Memory (OOM) error with exit code 52. 

And :
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException

Thank you!

Can you post your code? broadcast should work here.

result = DF1.join(broadcast(DF2), how='outer', on='key_column')

how many rows in each partition in df1? To make my point, if you have just 2 partitions with 216 million rows in each, then it's obviously going to go OOM trying to produce 3 billion rows (216m x 14) on each worker. You'll have to repartition df1 with better partitioning columns.

I have partition by the join_key that has only 11 values (so I partition in 11).

But when I tried to do an outer join between DF1 not partitioned and another dataframe DF3 that is bigger (with 10 million rows) it works without partitioning. Do you know why?

@Kashyap - OP is using an outer join, not a cross join, so the resultant dataframe should contain at most 433 million + 14 rows.

@xuxu, you're right. I still do think it must be to do with a hot spot (hot partition) problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210871/cassandra-data-modeling-time-series-avoiding-hot-spots and picking the right partitioning columns will help.

@pat_triccia - At what point do you materialize the result dataframe i.e. what do you do with the result dataframe subsequently? Can you post the exact error message as well?

@xuxu I tried to be more explicite, thank you

My bad, looking at the explain plan, I just realized broadcast is not supported for full outer join - See https://towardsdatascience.com/strategies-of-spark-join-c0e7b4572bcf. You can instead switch to couple of left joins and union the result.
result2 = broadcast(DF2).join(DF1, how='left', on='key_column')

result = result1.unionByName(result2)


Also spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold is set to too high a value. The default value of 10MB should do well enough for just 14 rows.

Thank you very much! I saw this error but several colleges insist that outer join with broadcast was possible! I'm going to try you solution.

Hi @xuxu. I tried your code and result2 = broadcast(DF2).join(DF1, how='left' is not supported by the broadcast. When the small df is in the left side, we can not do a broadcast. I found this if you want to check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735494/broadcast-join-in-spark-not-working-for-left-outer

Bummer. df_big.join(broadcast(df_small), 'key_column', 'left').unionByName(df_big.join(broadcast(df_small), 'key_column', 'right')).count() worked for me with dataframes of 433 million rows x 14 rows, even though explain shows SortMergeJoin was employed for the second join. Are you still getting an OOM?
